# No have 3D depth in Google XR cardboard plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I built the original hellocardboard sample code () and the left and right eye see from same position. No 3D depth feelings. How I can set 3D stereo?
I have 2560x1440 phone resolution and Gear VR. The VR set by right QRCode.
What can I do?
[image]

You can see this screenshot with crosseye method (if you want) and you can see a fixed depth from frame and the envi no have any other distance.

A created a similar space for compare:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I was able to find the following issue comment:

https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard/issues/207#issuecomment-779668776

Basically, it is saying you have to rebuild the Google Cardboard library.  I have forked the Cardboard XR Plugin library, and rebuilt the Cardboard plugin for Android in the following GitHub repo:

https://github.com/lmandres/cardboard-xr-plugin.git

To use it, follow the Cardboard XR Plugin install directions, but substitute the Google XR URL with the revised repo.